# iOS 15 - Reset app tracking ID?

Tags: ios

I use an app that seem to identify me no matter which account I'm signed in, even if I reinstall the app and sign in to another account, the app is still able to link me to my previous accounts used on that iPhone.

I think this is only possible because the app is able to read my device identifier, or a tracking ID used for ad targeting.

I'm on iOS 15.0.2, is there a way to reset this tracking ID (if there's one)?

Comment: Knowing what app it is might help you get an answer...

Comment: @SteveChambers I don't think which third-party app it is matters to this question.